# Getting request.path in django template tags

Tags: django

I want to create a custom filter for django templates. I've got some currency pairs (which are links) that I pass to my html page so I need to check if current url is equal to a currency pair from my list, then I gotta skip it.

For example, my url is:

```
https://website.com/usd/eur/
```

So if there's a pair USD/EUR, it won't be shown on my page.

To do this, I need to loop over all pairs and compare them to request.path value. So, how can I get it within my template **tags** ?

Comment: @pankaj's answer it correct, but why do you want to do all of this in the template? If you define your url pattern with the two variables /<cur1>/<cur2>/ you could do this processing in the view, which would make for more readable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly receive `request` into template tags like -

```
@register.simple_tag(name='new_tag')
def new_tag(request):
    path = request.path
    ....
```

and then in your html  use it like `{% new_tag request %}`.